# JSF/Seam - new component instance on submit?

Tags: java, jsf, seam

And my confusion with JSF continues. This is a continuation of a [question asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493671/jsf-seam-call-one-component-method-for-many-radio-groups), but I feel it warrants a new question. I have a single seam component that expects a URL parameter to be injected for retrieving a `List<String>` from a method. This works perfectly on the first navigation to the page. The `List` is used to display many different `selectOneRadio` groups that populate a `<h:form/>`.

Now on the submit, I cannot get the URL parameter to be injected or otherwise set on the component! Adding `<h:inputHidden/>` causes FacesExceptions to be thrown.

Then I tried setting the `List` as an instance variable on the object, and when the subsequent call is made on the submit (which I also do not understand why that is done) I check to see if the variable is non-null: if it isn't, return it.

Now I found that a new instance of the component is created on submit!!!

```
getList() called
this.toString(): .BeanAction@5fd98420

#### This is when submit is clicked
getList() called
this.toString(): .BeanAction@22aacbce
```

The component has the following annotations:

```
Stateful
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Name("bean")
@Restrict("#{identity.loggedIn}")
```

Can someone explain why there is a new instance of the component created?
I'm really not quite sure how to go about handling this. I thought the hidden parameter would work, because that is how I would do it with straight HTML, and I'm a little surprised that its not working for JSF/Seam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit upon the solution, but I still dont understand why it is required. By adding `<S:conversationId/>` to the `<h:commandButton/>` tag I am now getting the conversationId propagated across the form submit.

However, the seam documentation states:

```
If you don't do anything special, a non-faces request  (a GET request for example)
will not propagate the conversation context and will be processed in a new 
temporary conversation.
```

Which means Seam/JSF was treating my form submit as a "non-faces request". Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the page (or after the submit), do you see a conversation id in the url?  I am concerned that perhaps the Seam Conversation is not being initialized correctly.

Comment: The method `getList()` is marked with `@Begin`, and I can refresh the page that displays my form any number of times and the same backing bean is used. When I click submit I am redirected to my `summary.xhtml` page, and there is a new `cid` URL parameter. How do I maintain the conversation across a submit..?

Comment: I tried this

    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
        <s:conversationPropagation type="join"/>
    </h:commandButton>

And I still get a new conversation id when I click submit